# Regex Expression to match the Pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure a regex that matches the pattern

```
}

{
one or more lines here
}
```

i;e a curly closing brace followed by zero or more empty lines followed by a curly opening brace followed by zero or more lines of any text followed by a curly closing bracket.

I tried the following :

```
/}\s*{.\n*}/
```

with the following explanation:

```
} - matches the character } literally
\s* zero or more character [\r\n\t\f ]
{ matches the character { literally
. matches any character (except newline)
\n* matches 0 or more line-feed (newline)
} matches the character } literally
```

This however does not match.

Please point out what am I doing wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
}\s*{[^}]*}
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/29

Your regex

> {.\n*}

effectively quantifies `\n` instead of `.`.So it matches `a character and any number of \n's`.